# lisp nth function does not work on cons-cell

Tags: lisp, elisp

How to use nth function in lisp if my my variable is combination of list and cons-cell 
for eg:
`(setq aa '(1 2) )`
`(nconc aa (+ 1 2))`
 this return me `(1 2 . 3)`
when i say `(nth 1 aa)` it returns 2
but when i use `(nth 2 aa )` it throws error

Answer (score 8):

NTH returns the car of the nth (0, 1, 2 ...) cons cell.

Since your second cdr is not a cons cell it is an error to get the car of it.

```
(nthcdr 2 '(1 2 . 3))   returns 3
(last '(1 2 . 3))  returns (2 . 3)
```

Usually it is a good idea to avoid improper lists, where the cdr of some cell is not a cons or NIL.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  Another way to say it is: "don't do that, then".